# Suppress warnings from specific folder in Bazel

Tags: clang, bazel

I have a Bazel workspace with my own project, which also uses an external project. The layout looks like this

```
* workspace/
|-- my_project/
|-- some_other_project/
|-- outside/
|---- external_project
```

Everything is in the same language (C++), and I have gotten `my_project` (which depends on `external_project`) to compile correctly, and everything is going fine.

I would like to enable warnings for my projects and disable them for anything inside the `outside/` folder (and also anything in the system headers). I'm adding the warnings by adding

```
compiler_flag: "-Weverything"
compiler_flag: "-isystem/path-to-my-workspace/outside"
```

to my toolchain.

The problem is that now Bazel complains with

```
The include path '/path-to-my-workspace/outside' references a path outside of the execution root.
```

I get that this is probably done for security reasons, but I would still like to not be bothered by `other_project` warnings... I know I could be using `new_external_repository`, but I would like to maintain my whole workspace as a mono-repo (and also I'm not 100% that would work).

Is there a way to specify a global "warnings flag" that then gets overridden on a per-folder basis?